# iOS - Re-adding subview after all subviews are removed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I am making a ball program whereby you add a ball UIView subview to the superview on a Long Press Gesture. Tapping the view removes it from the superview.

Adding all views works great and re-adding views works fine as along as there's at least one view left in the superview. However, once all subviews are removed, the long press is supposed to re-add the first subview again, but instead the program shuts down.

I get only a release message in one of the threads, leading me to believe this is an alloc/dealloc issue, but ARC forbids me from releasing views explicitly, and I believe `[removeFromSuperview]` does that anyway.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. The particular methods of interest are `tapped:` and `createBall` after tapped: has been used on all subviews.

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecog;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecog;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecog;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIDynamicAnimator *anim;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer* timer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *orangeBall, *blueBall;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint ballCenter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* ballsArray;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect originalBounds;

@property (nonatomic) UIAttachmentBehavior *attachmentBehavior;
@property (nonatomic) UIPushBehavior *pushBehavior;
@property (nonatomic) UIDynamicItemBehavior *ballPhysics;
@property (nonatomic) UICollisionBehavior *collisionBehavior;

-(void)physics;
-(void)createBall;

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Prepare to handle Long Press to create ball object
    self.longPressRecog = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
    self.longPressRecog.minimumPressDuration = 0.8f;
    [self.longPressRecog setDelegate:self];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.longPressRecog];
}

// Handles Long Presses and creates a ball within the view
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if ([sender isEqual:self.longPressRecog]) {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            [self createBall];
        }
    }
}

// Set Ball Attributes
- (void)setOrangeBall {
    if (self.viewLoaded) {
        // Load ball view to screen
        self.orangeBall = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
        self.orangeBall.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0;
        self.orangeBall.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        self.orangeBall.layer.borderColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
        self.orangeBall.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
        [self.view addSubview:self.orangeBall];
    } else {

    }
}

- (void)setBlueBall {
    // Load ball view to screen
    self.blueBall = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160.0, 160.0, 50.0, 50.0)];
    self.blueBall.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0;
    self.blueBall.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.blueBall.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    self.blueBall.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    [self.view addSubview:self.blueBall];
}


// Create Balls
- (void)createBall {
    if (![_orangeBall superview] && ![_blueBall superview]) {
        [self setOrangeBall];
    } else if ([_orangeBall superview] && ![_blueBall superview]) {
        [self setBlueBall];
    } else {
        // NOTHING
    }

    // Begin animations
    self.anim = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

    // Init Physics
    [self physics];
}

// Gravity
- (void)physics {

    //Add ball objects to NSMutableArray. Needed in order to add behaviors to all ball objects.
    self.ballsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:self.orangeBall, self.blueBall, nil];

    //Tapping Behavior
    _tapRecog.delegate = self;
    for (UIView *ball in _ballsArray) {
        ball.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        _tapRecog = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
        [_tapRecog setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
        [ball addGestureRecognizer:_tapRecog];
    }
}

- (void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    //Delete tapped ball
    [recognizer.view willRemoveSubview:recognizer.view];
    [recognizer.view removeFromSuperview];
}


@end
```

Here's all I could really find from the thread errors:

```
UIKit`UIApplicationMain:
    0x10acd4bc9 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x10acd4bca <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10acd4bcd <+4>:   pushq  %r15
    0x10acd4bcf <+6>:   pushq  %r14
    0x10acd4bd1 <+8>:   pushq  %r13
    0x10acd4bd3 <+10>:  pushq  %r12
    0x10acd4bd5 <+12>:  pushq  %rbx
    0x10acd4bd6 <+13>:  pushq  %rax
    0x10acd4bd7 <+14>:  movq   %rcx, %rbx
    0x10acd4bda <+17>:  movq   %rsi, -0x30(%rbp)
    0x10acd4bde <+21>:  movl   %edi, %r12d
    0x10acd4be1 <+24>:  movq   0xe7f7b8(%rip), %r13      ; (void *)0x0000000109c12cb0: objc_retain
    0x10acd4be8 <+31>:  movq   %rdx, %rdi
    0x10acd4beb <+34>:  callq  *%r13
    0x10acd4bee <+37>:  movq   %rax, %r14
    0x10acd4bf1 <+40>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x10acd4bf4 <+43>:  callq  *%r13
    0x10acd4bf7 <+46>:  movq   %rax, %r15
    0x10acd4bfa <+49>:  leaq   0x11dab6b(%rip), %r13     ; _UIApplicationLinkedOnVersion
    0x10acd4c01 <+56>:  movl   (%r13), %eax
    0x10acd4c05 <+60>:  testl  %eax, %eax
    0x10acd4c07 <+62>:  jne    0x10acd4c17               ; <+78>
    0x10acd4c09 <+64>:  cmpq   $-0x1, 0x11d4ab7(%rip)    ; WebKitSetIsClassic + 7
    0x10acd4c11 <+72>:  jne    0x10acd4c8a               ; <+193>
    0x10acd4c13 <+74>:  movl   (%r13), %eax
    0x10acd4c17 <+78>:  cmpl   $0x20100, %eax            ; imm = 0x20100 
    0x10acd4c1c <+83>:  jb     0x10acd4c42               ; <+121>
    0x10acd4c1e <+85>:  callq  0x10b8f8a8a               ; symbol stub for: objc_autoreleasePoolPush
    0x10acd4c23 <+90>:  movq   %rax, %r13
    0x10acd4c26 <+93>:  movl   %r12d, %edi
    0x10acd4c29 <+96>:  movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rsi
    0x10acd4c2d <+100>: movq   %r14, %rdx
    0x10acd4c30 <+103>: movq   %r15, %rcx
    0x10acd4c33 <+106>: callq  0x10acd4ca2               ; _UIApplicationMainPreparations
    0x10acd4c38 <+111>: movq   %r13, %rdi
    0x10acd4c3b <+114>: callq  0x10b8f8a84               ; symbol stub for: objc_autoreleasePoolPop
    0x10acd4c40 <+119>: jmp    0x10acd4c54               ; <+139>
    0x10acd4c42 <+121>: movl   %r12d, %edi
    0x10acd4c45 <+124>: movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rsi
    0x10acd4c49 <+128>: movq   %r14, %rdx
    0x10acd4c4c <+131>: movq   %r15, %rcx
    0x10acd4c4f <+134>: callq  0x10acd4ca2               ; _UIApplicationMainPreparations
    0x10acd4c54 <+139>: movq   0x11daa55(%rip), %rdi     ; UIApp
    0x10acd4c5b <+146>: movq   0x11489d6(%rip), %rsi     ; "_run"
    0x10acd4c62 <+153>: callq  *0xe7f728(%rip)           ; (void *)0x0000000109c15ac0: objc_msgSend
    0x10acd4c68 <+159>: movq   0xe7f729(%rip), %rbx      ; (void *)0x0000000109c12d20: objc_release
    0x10acd4c6f <+166>: movq   %r15, %rdi
    0x10acd4c72 <+169>: callq  *%rbx
    0x10acd4c74 <+171>: movq   %r14, %rdi
    0x10acd4c77 <+174>: callq  *%rbx
    0x10acd4c79 <+176>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x10acd4c7b <+178>: addq   $0x8, %rsp
    0x10acd4c7f <+182>: popq   %rbx
    0x10acd4c80 <+183>: popq   %r12
    0x10acd4c82 <+185>: popq   %r13
    0x10acd4c84 <+187>: popq   %r14
    0x10acd4c86 <+189>: popq   %r15
    0x10acd4c88 <+191>: popq   %rbp
    0x10acd4c89 <+192>: retq   
    0x10acd4c8a <+193>: leaq   0x11d4a37(%rip), %rdi     ; _UIApplicationLinkedOnVersionOnce
    0x10acd4c91 <+200>: leaq   0xe82d08(%rip), %rsi      ; __block_literal_global.1554
    0x10acd4c98 <+207>: callq  0x10b8f92d6               ; symbol stub for: dispatch_once
    0x10acd4c9d <+212>: jmp    0x10acd4c13               ; <+74>
```

Comment: If you want people to read your question, please don't post irrelevant code (e.g. `updateView`, `didReceiveMemoryWarning`). Figuring out the minimum amount of code for which your problem is occurring may also help you hone in on the root cause. Does the problem still occur if you remove the `physics` method, or the `ballDragged` method (or parts of them)? If not, don't include them.

Comment: Improved, but does setting the ball colors, etc affect the behaviour? If not, remove those methods. Remove any properties that don't relate to the issue at hand. Keep going until you have the bare minimum of code that shows the problem. You might find it useful to create a new temporary project of your own for investigating this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you double-tap a "ball", you remove that view from its superview:

```
- (void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    //Delete tapped ball
    [recognizer.view willRemoveSubview:recognizer.view];
    [recognizer.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

However, that "ball" still exists. On the next long-press, your code skips over creating the balls (because they both exist), but in the ball create method is where you add them to the main view. When your code drops into physics method, you try to add a collision behavior to a view that is not in the hierarchy.

You should either delete your "balls" (set them to nil) when you remove them from their superViews, or re-add them as subviews the next time around.

This is one way, although not the best...

```
- (void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    //Delete tapped ball
    [recognizer.view willRemoveSubview:recognizer.view];
    [recognizer.view removeFromSuperview];

    if (recognizer.view == _blueBall) {
        _blueBall = nil;
    } else if (recognizer.view == _orangeBall) {
        _orangeBall = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually tried using `_orangeBall = nil` but without the if conditions and it didn't help, but this worked great. My code needs a lot of refactoring, but my main goal is functionality right now. Still new to Objective-C. Thanks for the help!